# Datermine the time complexity of an algorithm calculating the sum of Euler $\phi$ function.

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, totient-function

Firstly, the Euler $\phi$ function in this problem is same as [wiki:Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function).

The algorithm's input is a single number $N$, and its outpus is $\sum_{i=1}^n \phi(i)$.

For simplify, I'd like using $S(n)$ to represent for $\sum_{i=1}^n \phi(i)$.

The algorithm mainly uses the formula: $$\sum_{i=1}^nS(\frac{N}{i})=\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$$
as we know $\frac{N}{i}$ has $O(\sqrt{N})$ different results, so does $S(\frac{N}{i})$,
now every thing is prepared and the algorithm works as:

1.Calculate the table of $\phi$ up to $N^\frac{2}{3}$ by **sieve of eratosthenes**, and the corresponding $S$ is known.

2.Use the formula above, then $S(N)=\frac{N(N+1)}{2}-\sum_{i=2}^nS(\frac{N}{i})$, use the speed-up trick and calculate the remains like $S(\frac{N}{2})$ by recursion.

And here are my questions:

1.How to analyse the time complexity of this algorithm.

2.The calculation in step 1. involves a constant $\frac{2}{3}$, and I wonder if there exist a better constant which could improve the total time complexity, for example $1-\frac{1}{e}$ or $\frac{7}{10}$.

3.Any better algorithm than this in calculating the sum of $\phi$ function?